# Inner join returns nothing and left outer join returns NULL - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This query returns nothing at all when I use an INNER JOIN but when I change it to a LEFT OUTER JOIN I get a NULL value.

```
SELECT                  RMDET.CUST_CODE,
                        OHORDER.SHIP_TO_NAME,
                        RMDET.TRAN_REF_NO,
                        RMDET.TRAN_DATE,
                        RMDET.TRAN_AMT
FROM                    RMDET (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN         OHORDER (NOLOCK) ON OHORDER.ORDER_NO = RMDET.TRAN_REF_NO
WHERE                   RMDET.TRAN_AMT_APPLIED = 0
ORDER BY                RMDET.CUST_CODE
```

Output:

```
CUST_CODE   SHIP_TO_NAME    TRAN_REF_NO     TRAN_DATE           TRAN_AMT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
101         NULL            5181            2020-02-13          30.21
101         NULL            5593            2020-02-18          102.07
106         NULL            232793          2019-10-25          66.19
107         NULL            5476            2020-02-17          345.00
107         NULL            3230            2020-01-20          194.00
```

It should show "AC Hotel" which is 101 instead of NULL and so on. The OHORDER.ORDER_NO and RMDET.TRAN_REF_NO are Primary Keys but I think the problem may be the columns in the tables are unrelated. How do I check?

Here is the data from RMDET:

```
CUST_CODE   TRAN_REF_NO TRAN_TYPE   TRAN_DATE   TRAN_AMT    TRAN_AMT_APPLIED    
      101          5181         I   2020-02-13     30.21    0.00
```

And from OHORDER:

```
ORDER_NO     CUST_CODE     SHIP_TO_CODE         SHIP_TO_NAME
    5181           101                S         AC HOTEL
```

There are more columns but they are not relevant to the query.

Comment: Then the problem may be with your data.

Comment: please show some sample data from `RMDET` and `OHORDER`

Comment: *I think the problem may be the columns in the tables are unrelated.* How do you expect any sort of JOIN to work properly if the columns in the tables are unrelated? Can you provide sample data from both tables?

Comment: I just edited the question, thanks all

Comment: PS, OHORDER is an order that we create in the database. It is then turned into an invoice and eventually paid. RMDET records the payment. I want to see all invoices that are not paid. I hope that might help.

Comment: Every thing seams Okay, and Inner join retrieved one row, and left join retrieved the same row too, Double Check into Structure of your tables are they similar to [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a6f0e7/1)?

Comment: What is data types for OHORDER.ORDER_NO & RMDET.TRAN_REF_NO?

Comment: Hi, thanks Ahmed, let me look into that. Viv - thanks also. The ORDER_NO is char and wow, I literally just checked and the TRAN_REF_NO is varchar! Is that the problem?!

Comment: PS, sorry for the delay, I forgot to check back and I just got the notification email that I had replies.